# How to configure AngularFire for Multiple Firebase Projects

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am attempting to configure my [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) (2.3.0) - (This uses Angular 1.x) app to handle multiple firebase projects. Firebase has a reference in their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) for this possibility. Here is a snippet of how to initialize a single database.

```
// Initialize Firebase
// TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Here is how you would add another database.

```
var secondaryAppConfig = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};

// Initialize another app with a different config
var secondary = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");

// Retrieve the database.
var secondaryDatabase = secondary.database();
```

Can AngularFire recognize and distinguish between multiple projects?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw3pyc?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts ?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav and I am using AngularFire 2.3 with Angular 1.x. What you referenced is for Angular2 and AngularFire2. I'll make a better note of which versions I am using above.

Comment: @R.Richards See my reply to Sharikov

Comment: True. My bad...

Comment: Re-tagged for angularjs

Comment: From a quick scan of the project's code it looks like it always initializes based on the default `firebaseApp`. That would mean it's indeed not possible to use two projects with AngularFire 2.x.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is what I figured. Guess I'll have to use the vanilla Firebase API and call a bunch of $scope.$apply. :/

Comment: Issue reported on https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/958

Answer (score 0):

Yes angularFire can do it => tested with : "angular": "~1.5.3", "angularfire": "^2.0.1"

Secondary DB from another project (different auth !) :

```
    constructor(Firebase, $firebaseArray){
      'ngInject';

      this.firebase = Firebase;
      this.app = Firebase.initializeApp(secondaryConfig, 'secondary');
      this.$firebaseArray = $firebaseArray;
    }

    getListDb1 () {
      const refList = this.firebase.database().ref(`items`);
      return this.$firebaseArray(refList);
    }

    getListDb2 () {
      const refList = this.app.database().ref('items');
      return this.$firebaseArray(refList);
    }
```

I couldn't achieve to access 2 DBs from the same project with the same Auth in AngularFire but I have the solution for AF2 if someone needs it, just ask.

Comment: any chance you can add the AF2 same Auth code here too please.  Is a good location as one of the first google search results is this page

Comment: the AF2 solution is right here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924782/access-multiple-realtime-databases-of-the-same-firebase-app-project/50418555#50418555
Sorry for the late answer